# Lissajous Figure in SHM

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator, vibrations

*Question*
In an experiment to obtain Lissajous figures, one tuning fork is of 256Hz and a circular figure occur after every five seconds. What deductions may be made about the frequency of the other tuning fork?
*Tried with beats*

$|f-256|=1/5$
$f-256= _-^+0.2$
$f=256_-^+0.2$
Please help to solve is this right or is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain Lissajou's figures you need *multiples/sub-multiples* of frequencies of SHMs at right angles but not small frequency differences. Or frequencies can have a simple ratio like 5:6 or 9:10

But to obtain beats a small increase or decrease of frequency between forks is required as you said, however the physical phenomenon is quite different.

Comment: then how could I solve this

Comment: can I have a complete answer as I can't understand this phenomenon

Comment: see Mathworld under the topic. Many examples including phase difference are given.